# how to construct a database of smart contract holders addresses and the amount they hold?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, blockchain

my question is regarding the db design i am using mongodb
i create collection for every contract and store holders and the amount they hold

i got an information that there is expected to be 1.5m smart contracts( i am sure most of them are people learning and don't have many transactions and a lot of holders)

i needed better approach rather than having 1,5m collections most of them having less than 10 documents

here is my idea since every holder can have tokens on multiple smart contracts i can create one collection and store the holder address and store an array of documents each has contract address and amount held by the holder address more over i can use each contract address as field and the amount as value to not have to query the array when i add or subtract from the amount

if u have better approach share it in the answer

if u are interested on the whole process or it may help u answer better(with first approach)

i have a node.js server that takes post request to analyze a contract by supplying contract address and the block number of first transaction the function then starts by connecting to a node to access the blockchain i am doing BNB for now and listen to the transfer event from block number of default 0 getting transactions of the contract every 10k blocks and then process them and get the next transactions in the next 10k blocks

processing:
a function that takes the (transactions,contract address, and last block number checked) first i loop through the transaction extracting all from and to addresses and query the db to go to the collection of the contract address and retrieve the documents of the addresses they come into an array my next step is to transform them into one object of {address:amount} using map for O(1) access instead of searching the array everytime i want to get an address ,next i loop through transactions again checking if the to address is in my object if it is i add the transaction value if not i add it to object with the transaction value then check if the from is there if it's i subtract if it's not i just continue (minting , burning , creation, destruction) i send the modified object and lat block checked to update query and go though them checking on the value if it's 0 i delete if not i update the address with the value with upsert set to true at last i update the last block checked so i can continue later from last point then use bulkwrite and transactions to insure the Atomicity

environment
mongodb nodejs driver 5.5.0
node 16.6